# Sequelize update or create included association

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

Having Sequelize `hasOne` associations:

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {/* ... */})
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {/* ... */})

// One-way association
User.hasOne(Project)
```

and user instance **already exists**. How do we add a new `Project` and connect it to the `User` instance?

Firstly, we need to find the `User`:

```
const user = await models.users.findOne({
    where: { id: 1 },
    include: models.projects
});
```

What do we do next? What if `user.project` is `null`?

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

`Project.belongsTo(User)`

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to.js~BelongsTo.html

Comment: I can use `belongsTo`, but question is how do creation the right way when `Project` doesn't exist yet. I solved the problem, I just need to know the best practice.